# Assistance with Error: Start tag body seen but an element of the same type was already open and Error: Stray end tag head

Tags: html

I have been having an issue with my code to get it validated with no errors on the w3c validator site. I was wondering if any of you could possibly help me. I edited this but the copy paste is being buggy so i included the screenshot as well.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbnP5.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wW9m.png)

```
<title>About</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<img src="Images/Logo.png" alt="Logo image">
<h1><strong>CloudGaming</strong></h1>
<a href="Index.html">Home</a>
<a href="Contents.html">Contents</a>
<a href="Products.html">Products</a>
<a href="News.html">News</a>
<a href="About.html">About</a>
```

```
<h1><u><strong>About:</strong></u></h1>
<p>I am a Cloud Computing student and this site is all about cloud gaming. This website will include all up to date
    information on the topic from what its about, how it works,<br> why its so popular nowadays, and what the pros
    and cons of switching over to it are. On the products page, there is sections of different types of products
    that are used in cloud gaming today and what the best ones are.<br> This website also includes links to websites
    that go further into detail about certain brands that support cloud computing such as Nvidia Geforce NOW, Amazon
    Luna, and Vortex. </p>

<img src="Images/About.png" alt="About image">
<footer>
    <a href="duganzach2002@gmail.com">Personal Email</a>
</footer>
```

Comment: Please do not post code as images. Nobody can edit/execute that.

Comment: The code you’ve provided won’t cause that error (because the error is complaining about `</head>` being somewhere it isn’t allowed and you don’t have `</head>` in the code you shared.

Comment: @Quentin I need to edit it i guess. i just copy and pasted it from my visual studio code. it isnt showing up for some reason...

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what the context is or where the markup is coming from but the "title" and "meta" tasks should be in the head tags never in the body with the rest of the html